# What's the best practice .net Architecture for a single simple json web service?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services, json

So I know of 3 .net Architecture's that can easily provide json data in the form of a web service:

1)  Classic ASMX web service
2)  ASP.NET MVC action that returns a json result.
3)  WCF
(also there is probably a way to use ASP.NET Web Forms AJAX, but I'm not going there)

I've worked with all 3 before, and it seems like a Classic ASMX web service is the right pick for this job.  But I'm not sure if web services are the preferred way of providing json data in a .net environment anymore.

The project will just have one web service and nothing else, at this point.

What's the microsoft (tm) preferred Architecture of creating a simple json web service these days?

Comment: There are certainly more than 3. Those are just the big ones from MS. Here's one that I was looking at this weekend and there are plenty others http://manosdemono.org/

Comment: @kenny Yeah, sure i use a variety of ones, but for some jobs companies only want official non-open source .net solutions.  That is the explicit scope in which I asked the question, according to the last sentence.

Comment: FYI ASP.NET MVC is open-source

Comment: @kenny You know what I mean, Asp.net mvc, like jQuery has been given the official microsoft sign of approval.  It is after all "asp .net" mvc and comes installed in some versions of visual studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your application is an ASP.NET MVC application, you don't need anything else. Just create a controller which returns JsonResult class

Also, you could give WCF Web API a try : http://wcf.codeplex.com/releases/view/64449

Watch some of the videos of Glenn Block here;

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM14

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/DevDays/DevDays-2011-Netherlands/Devdays103